# Why when I upload of file-list the server-side code get an empty list?

Tags: jquery-file-upload

First of all here's [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zandam/dhxe54ob/), so you can see what I'm talking abuout.
I'm using blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload to manage files in the GUI of my asp-net application (server-side code is OK). If I manage the upload one-by-one I am able to upload that file successfully but as I try to submit the whole list the server does not recognize data and get only an empty list.
Here's the piece of code where my issue is:

```
//initialize fileupload()
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    //I call this function when I add file(s) to the list
    add: function (e, data) { 
        //I do some more actions here
        //Then I define this function when the submit button is clicked
        $('#submitButton').click(function () {
            //fix this?
            data.submit();
        });
    }    
)};
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your server should support multipart forms!

A solid handler for ASP.NET is [Backload](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/tree/master/)

Comment: If you need to handle the request yourself, be sure to parse the content type, get the boundary and split the body into segments.